# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header error during Client Credentials Request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I need to enable API access for a background service so that it will not require manual user login. Application is written in Javascript ( Angular ).

I have followed the steps for the consent process / access token in the following [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) but I am getting a CORS error.

**Admin Consent Confirmation - Working**

[image]

**Access Token Request - Failing**

The consent returns a tenant which I use for the next step

```js
let payload = {
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID_HERE',
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET_HERE',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
};
$http.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant + '/oauth2/v2.0/token', payload);
```

[image: Failed request]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, **do not put client secrets in front-end JavaScript**.

The client credentials grant flow is not meant to be used from the front-end. That's why you get the CORS error.

You need to enable Implicit Grant flow for your app. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit.

Then you can get an access token right in the first response from AAD. Or you can request it via a hidden iframe. Msal.js can help you a lot here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js.